# How to find the Tolls in Google Map API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Map API 3.0 to calculate the distance of two places. I can calculate it easily.

But now I need to find out every bridge or ferry service tolls (if any).

For example if I try to get the route direction of [DFW Airport, Grapevine, TX, USA] to [McKinney, TX, USA] in Google Map I get “This route has tolls”.
But using Google Map API I can’t find it. How can I figure out this?

Comment: You should use [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) as it is designed to search for places and get it's details.

Comment: I'm stuck exactly at your point (Google Maps gives advices about tolls and ferries; Google Maps API totally ignore these), and still look for an answer

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Google Maps gives advice about tolls and ferries.
But Google Maps API totally ignore these.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.