# How to recognise toll booths in google maps api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make an app which recognises all the toll booth which are between source and destination. Google maps API has a avoidTolls but nothing specific to recognise the toll booths. Can I get advice on how to solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the Tolls in Google Map API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649518/how-to-find-the-tolls-in-google-map-api)

Answer (score 2):

As [confirmed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44173447/6309), the Google API alone would ignore those (toll booths)

Maybe the [Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) might help searching and locating toll booths.

[S.P.H.I.N.X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426383/s-p-h-i-n-x) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954690/how-to-recognise-toll-booths-in-google-maps-api/47954699?noredirect=1#comment82890797_47954699) to the [Place types API](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=en)... but it does not include "toll booth".

Comment: You can check locations supported by the place api [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=en). However, I did not find any toll booths.

Comment: @S.P.H.I.N.X OK, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.